# Stripe Webhook Errors: Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given

Tags: php, stripe-payments, webhooks

I'm not sure why I'm getting the following errors on my webhook php file. I'm following the example almost exactly to what Stripe has in their docs (https://stripe.com/docs/payments/handling-payment-events). However I get the warnings/errors below.

The warnings I'm getting when I go directly to the webhook page. I'm also seeing these errors in the response body in the Stripe dashboard. I'm using the Stripe Webhook CLI tool and triggering a `charge.succeeded` event, however it seems like the `case` for that never catches it and `HELLO3` is always echoed out in the response.

`( ! ) Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in /stripe/stripe-php/lib/StripeObject.php on line 272`

`Warning: array_diff(): Argument #2 is not an array in /stripe/stripe-php/lib/StripeObject.php on line 272`

`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /stripe/stripe-php/lib/Util/Set.php on line 15`

`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /stripe/stripe-php/lib/StripeObject.php on line 295`

`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /stripe/stripe-php/lib/StripeObject.php on line 280`

```
<?php

//load Stripe API
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/stripe/stripe-php/init.php');

// Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production!
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');

$payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$event = null;


try {
    $event = \Stripe\Event::constructFrom(
        json_decode($payload, true)
    );
} catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
    // Invalid payload
    http_response_code(400);
    exit();
}

// Handle the event
switch ($event->type) {
    case 'charge.succeeded':
        $paymentIntent = $event->data->object; // contains a StripePaymentIntent
        handlePaymentIntentSucceeded($paymentIntent);

        wp_publish_post( 36 );

        echo "HELLO";

        break;
    case 'payment_method.attached':
        $paymentMethod = $event->data->object; // contains a StripePaymentMethod
        handlePaymentMethodAttached($paymentMethod);
        echo "HELLO2";
        break;

    // ... handle other event types
    default:
        // Unexpected event type
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "HELLO3";
        exit();
}

http_response_code(200);

?>
```

Comment: If you log out `event.type` what are you getting? Can you narrow down what part of your code leads to those error messages?

Comment: Visiting the URL in your browser is unlike to work because it will be a GET request, and won't have the expected `body` payload of a intended POST request.

Comment: @NolanH yeah I figured.. but I still get these warnings in the response. Also, the default case is getting put in the response as well, which doesn't make sense since I'm triggering a `charge.succeeded` event.

Comment: @NolanH The specific piece of code that leads to the errors is the try/catch portion.

Comment: Are you sure that is the event you're receiving? What do you see if you log the event type before the switch? Is the event successfully parsed with `json_decode()`? The messages appear to be warnings so many not actually be a problem.

Comment: I see what was going on now. When I'd access the php file directly it would show those warnings, which was normal because there was no data coming from Stripe. I read the response closer in the Stripe dashboard and it included a fatal error on the `handlePaymentIntentSucceeded()` function because it did not exist. I removed that and now everything works :)

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working for you @Dustin